# SQL Server 2012 query to calculate date and time difference

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

Hello I need to calculate the time difference on this timestamp transaction column, the format is as follows, I was triying to use the DATEDIFF function to no avail. Thanks for your help.

```
Txtimestamp
2016-01-05 12:16:51.000
2016-01-05 12:16:51.000
2016-01-18 12:24:16.000
2016-01-18 12:24:16.000
2016-01-20 08:15:32.000
2016-01-20 08:15:32.000
2016-01-20 12:24:29.000
2016-01-20 12:24:29.000
2016-01-29 12:18:11.000
2016-01-29 12:18:11.000
2016-02-01 12:16:43.000
2016-02-01 12:16:43.000
```

Comment: The time difference between what and what?

Comment: Between the first value from the list to the second and so on. and display the difference between them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had something like this in mind, but again it is not as crisp as Gordon's answer. I'm not sure what the performance difference would be. Probably a lot since this needs to perform two sub-queries...

```
 SELECT tA.txtimestamp, tB.txtimestamp, DATEDIFF(second, tA.txtimestamp, tB.txtimestamp) AS diff
 FROM (SELECT row_num = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY txtimestamp), txtimestamp
       FROM your_table) AS tA 
       INNER JOIN
      (SELECT row_num = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY txtimestamp), txtimestamp
       FROM your_table) AS tB ON tA.row_num = tB.row_num - 1
```

It is clunky, but certainly another possibility. You would need to modify the "-" in the join condition to a "+" depending on how you want the difference to come out.

Answer (score 3):

Do you want something like this?

```
select datediff(second, lag(txtimestamp) over (order by txtimestamp), txtimestamp) as diff_in_seconds
from t;
```

Comment: Wow, that's nifty. I would've added a row number column to the table and self-joined it using the row number minus one. This is much more crisp. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: Pat, can you please share the code for your last comment, I will like to try that one as well. Thanks